# Laravel Change Booking Status automaticly

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any way to change automatically the booking status to 'completed' order status after the service date is passed?

Basically, I want the $booking-> status to be changed to 'completed' after the end_date

will be an option to have a function
function booking_status_changer() {

Im new to Laravel and have not found anything that can help me accomplish this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest using either a mysql trigger, or set up a [scheduled job or command](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling) to update the statuses for you.

Comment: @aynber Thanks dear. will try to do it using Corn Job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you use `Background Jobs` with `Scheduler` in Laravel

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#introduction

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling

You can create a background job that requests the database to change the booking status to `completed` when a record has passed the deadline.